# Can Moblin run (and compile) Python scripts?

Tags: python, development-environment

I want to develop an app for Moblin for a competition.

The development environment needed by Moblin is too complicated to setup. It uses Anjuta as its IDE, but I could never make sense of the entire compilation toolchain.

However, I would like to know if Moblin could compile and run Python scripts. If I could write the app in Python instead of Anjuta, then my work would be a lot easier.

Please let me know..

--Rishi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not need to compile them, as it contains a Python interpreter already.